# Odd division result in swift

Tags: swift

Please consider following code:

```
print("votes count \(votesCount) allVotes \(survey.allVotesCount)")
print("value to return \(Double(votesCount / survey.allVotesCount))")
```

In log it output:

```
votes count 30 allVotes 31
value to return 0.0
```

Why result is 0? It suppose to be 0.96

Comment: You are doing integer division.

Comment: all votes int or double

Comment: @rmaddy but i did cast to double.

Comment: But you did it after the division. See the duplicate and its answer.